# How do you find a point where 2 points meet at a right angle in Python?

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, computational-geometry

As shown in image, I need to find point P3 in Python.

Thanks

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In a usual (x,y) Cartesian coordinate system(*), the point P3 is at coordinates `(P2.x, P1.y)`

[image]

(*) thanks to TigerHawk and Selcuk for their added precision.

Comment: Are you sure it's not `(P2.x, P1.y)`?

Comment: ahem... I was making sure you were not asleep TigerHawk... I corrected it, thanks.

Comment: What is wrong with the first answer? Who defines the coordinate system?